# remove comma between address/publisher and year and after parentheses

Tags: biblatex

I need citations (mostly) as footnotes in the following form:

Book first appearance:

> F. Author ­– T.S. Author, *The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle*, Address 1965, 4.

Second appearance:

> F. Author ­– T.S. Author, *Shorttitle* (cf. nt. 1) 5.

Article in journal first appearance:

> A. Author, "Title of the Article", *Journal Title* 65 (1968) 113­-126.

So far I got to:

> F. Author ­– T.S. Author, *The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle*, Address, 1965, 4.
>
> F. Author ­– T.S. Author, *Shorttitle* (cf. nt. 1), 5.
>
> A. Author, "Title of the Article", *Journal Title* 65 (1968), 113­-126.

As you see, I didn't achieve to get rid of the commas between address and year and after the two parentheses. So far I got with the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{Abook,
 author = "First Author and The Second Author",
 title = {The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle},
 shorttitle = {Shorttitle},
 publisher = "The Publisher",
 address =  "Address",
 year = "1965"}
@article{Aarticle,
Author = {Article Author},
Journal = {Journal Title},
Pages = {113-126},
Title = {Title of the Article},
Volume = {65},
Year = {1968}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}%
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\space\printtext{(}}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}})%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {)\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\iffirstinits{\let~\-}{}#1}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  seenote = {cf. nt.},
}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}

Here and there. \footcite[4]{Abook}

There and here. \footcite[5]{Abook}

Up and down. \footcite{Aarticle}

\end{document}
```

My first attempt to get any further was to use `\ifciteseen` the following way:

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{%
  \ifciteseen 
  {\space}
  {\addcomma\space}}
```

This does not work as also the first appearance is treated as already seen (I think because it is nested with another `\ifciteseen` inside `\newbibmacro*{footcite}`.

So my second try was:

```
\newbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\space}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}
```

This solved part of the problem, but created another one: It retained the comma in the first appearance of the book (god), removed the comma in the second appearance (god), added a space between the footnote number and the citation (bad).

For the commas between the address and year and after the parenthesis in the article citation I didn't find any idea how to proceed.

So any suggestions how to get rid of the three commas mentioned, without touching the others?

Comment: I'm sorry but this my first time to post here and I should obviously have used "pre" instead of "code", so my code got all mixed up. I could post it again if that helps.

Comment: It appears to me you have two accounts with the same name, one of which you used to ask the question, and the other to "answer" it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to insert `\nopunct` into appropriate places for these two different problems.

For the year, this is in the biblatex macro `issue+date` and you can insert it before the final `\newunit`:

```
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \nopunct\newunit}
```

For the see note, it should be part of your redefinition of `footnote:cite` after your closing parenthesis.  I would also suggest moving the opening parenthesis into the same block.

Putting this into your code, we get:

[image: Sample output]

from

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{Abook,
 author = "First Author and The Second Author",
 title = {The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle},
 shorttitle = {Shorttitle},
 publisher = "The Publisher",
 address =  "Address",
 year = "1965"}
@article{Aarticle,
Author = {Article Author},
Journal = {Journal Title},
Pages = {113-126},
Title = {Title of the Article},
Volume = {65},
Year = {1968}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}%
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext{%
  (%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}})\nopunct%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {)\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\iffirstinits{\let~\-}{}#1}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \nopunct\newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  seenote = {cf.~nt.\adddot},
}


\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}

Here and there. \footcite[4]{Abook}

There and here. \footcite[5]{Abook}

Up and down. \footcite{Aarticle}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved part of the problem (the extra space) by rewriting the \renewbibmacro*{footcite}:

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
   \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
   \ifciteseen%
   {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\space}\iffieldundef{shorthand}                                 {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}
    {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
   {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
    \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}
```

So what remains to be solved is the comma between address and year and after the parenthesis in the article citation.

Comment: I enabled cookies and hope to be recognized as the same user from now on.

Comment: Andrew's solution is of course much better. And points to the last step to the full solution. To remove the comma between address and year one has recode `publisher+location+date`. (Changing `\addcomma\space` to `\addspace` at the approriate place.)