# Making volume and number be part of Journal title in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, bibliographystyle

## **Problem Description**

I want to make the `volume` and `number` be part of `journal` with the `volume` number in *italics* and the `number` not in italics as shown in the picture below:
[image: Desired Output]
However, my output is separating the `volume` and `number` from the `journal` and the `volume` is not in *italics* as shown in the picture below:
[image: My problem description]
**My hunch is that this issue has something to do with the `apalike2.bst` file though I do not have any clue on where and what to modify on this file.**
Below is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wainwright2008graphical,
    author   = {Wainwright, M. J. and Jordan, M. I.},
    title    = {Graphical Models, Exponential Families, and Variational Inference},
    journal  = {Foundations and Trends\textsuperscript{\normalfont\footnotesize\textregistered} in Machine Learning},
    year     = {2008},
    volume   = {1},
    number   = {1--2},
    pages    = {1--305}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}

\begin{document} 
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress the comma after `journal title`, you can use the `add.blank` function. What this does is it adds a blank punctuation mark. The solution comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324449/remove-comma-after-year-in-bibliography) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636126/natbib-remove-comma-after-journal-name-if-volume-exist-in-bst).

In your local copy of `apalike2.bst`, find the `FUNCTION {article}` block. Add the following code before the block (doesn't matter where, so long as it precedes `FUNCTION {article}`):

```
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Then call this function in `FUNCTION {article}`, right after the line where it says `journal emphasize "journal" output.check`, like this:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
    add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm!

Comment: And the solution I have been looking came from a new contributor @Quae. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @itc ! Happy to help. It'd be great if you could award the bounty :)

Comment: Yes, I have awarded you the +50 reputation bounty. You deserve it! You have earned it!